# Is it OK not to ground a ceiling fan?

Tags: ceiling-fan

I'd like to install a ceiling fan in a room where the ceiling electrical box has no grounding wire. Is that OK to do?  If not, why not?

Answer (score 2):

If you're following the National Electrical Code, you have a few options.

### Install an insulated fixture

410.44 exception 1 allows you to not connect a grounding conductor, where the fixture is insulated and there are no exposed conductive parts.

### Install a ground

410.44 exception 2 allows you to install a grounding conductor in accordance with 250.130(c).  Which means you can connect a grounding conductor any of the following:

> (1) Any accessible point on the grounding electrode system as described in 250.50
> (2) Any accessible point on the grounding electrode conductor.
> (3) The equipment grounding terminal bar within the enclosure where the branch circuit for the receptacle or branch circuit originates.
> (4) An equipment grounding conductor that is part of another branch circuit that originates from the enclosure where the branch circuit for the receptacle or branch circuit originates.
> (5) For grounded systems, the grounded service conductor within the service equipment enclosure.
> (6) For ungrounded systems, the grounding terminal bar within the service equipment enclosure.

### GFCI protection

The final exception to 410.44 allows you to not connect the grounding conductor, where the fixture is GFCI protected.